# Want to make GRUB load automatically

Tags: grub2, 16.10, grub-legacy

The thing is GRUB doesn't load up automatically , I have to do it manually, so can someone tell me how can I make it load up automatically everytime I boot?

Comment: How are you doing it "manually"? What does show up, if you don't?

Comment: I hold shift when my laptop logo pops up

Comment: And if I don't it just boots into Ubuntu

Comment: Please, execute `cat /etc/default/grub` and edit your question with output

Comment: What you want to do is not to "load GRUB", it is to show the GRUB menu.

Comment: Um... Can u give me a text tutorial cos I'm a newbie with Ubuntu

Comment: I want it to show the GRUB automatically everytime I boot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to edit your `/etc/default/grub` file. 
Open terminal and type:
`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
(or replace by your favourite editor)

Place "#" at the start of line `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`, then simply run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Ok I'm in terminal I put # in front of GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0 now how do I save it

Comment: Never mind I found the solution and thanks a million @Erman